# Collect data from a named pipe for a period of time

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I want to analyse some data from a named pipe, for example:

```
cat trace_pipe | awk '{print $6}' | head -100000 | sort | uniq -c |
  sort -k 1 -nr
```

This command will collect first 100k lines of data from `trace_pipe`. Is there a way for me to collect data for 10 seconds rather than a limited number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the
[`timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout)
command, you might need to split the commands

```sh
timeout 10 cat trace_pipe > trace_pipe.cut
awk '{print $6}' trace_pipe.cut | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -nr
```